# catkin export cmake definitions/variables to depending packages

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to set cmake variables in one package and export them to all depending packages?

For clarity:

If I set a cmake variable in one packages CMakeLists.txt like:

```
set( My_Var "Hello World" )
```

I can it now has the value in this package, I can e. g. echo it like

```
message( "My_Var = ${My_Var}" )
```

which will result in the output:

```
My_Var = Hello World
```

However, if I put the same output in another package (which depends on the previous one), the result is empty:

```
message( "My_Var = ${My_Var}" )
```

Resulting output:

```
My_Var =
```

Apparently, both packages have separate cmake namespaces. Now Is there a way to set a variable in one package, the mark it in some kind of way to be exported into depending packages and access its value in the depending packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192350/catkin-export-cmake-definitions/variables-to-depending-packages/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-09-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found solution:

*##########################################################################

1 ) created a folder `cmake` in the "first package" and added a file `pkg_config_extras.cmake` into it. It contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

set( My_Var "Hello World" )
```

*##########################################################################

2. to make My_Var viewable in the "first package" 's CMakeLists.txt I added:

   include( cmake/pkg_config_extras.cmake )
   ----> now I can output it there with correct result:

   message( "My_Var = ${My_Var}" )
   ----> Result:

   My_Var = Hello World

*##########################################################################

3. to make My_Var viewable in the "second package" 's CMakeLists.txt ("second package" depends on the "first package") I needed to add in the "first package" 's CMakeLists.txt a  `CFG_EXTRAS` when calling `catkin_package`:

   catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include                  # unchanged, whatever was there before
   LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}             # unchanged, whatever was there before
   CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp                 # unchanged, whatever was there before
   DEPENDS OpenCV                        # unchanged, whatever was there before
   CFG_EXTRAS pkg_config_extras.cmake    # added this line !!!!
   )

----> now I can also output it in the "second package" 's CmakeLists.txt with correct result:

```
message( "My_Var = ${My_Var}" )
```

----> Result:

```
My_Var = Hello World
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I never used it and I haven't tried tried it but there's a `PARENT_SCOPE` parameter for `set`. See the [command reference](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html?highlight=set).

Maybe this works. I'm not a cmake expert.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-09-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1